# Как установить poetry 1.2.2 в Windows (WSL)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poetry

У меня была установлена `Poetry version 1.1.13` через команду `sudo apt install python3-poetry` сейчас хочу установить `Poetry version 1.2.2` в Windows (WSL). Для начала удаляю `poetry` командой `sudo apt remove python3-poetry` и затем пробую установить `Poetry` командой `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -` и ничего не получается, вот что выдает терминал:

```
Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

/home/em0ji/.local/bin

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.2.2): Restoring previously saved environment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 940, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 919, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 550, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 571, in install
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "<stdin>", line 643, in make_env
  File "<stdin>", line 629, in make_env
  File "<stdin>", line 344, in make
  File "<stdin>", line 367, in pip
  File "<stdin>", line 364, in python
  File "<stdin>", line 350, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1847, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/em0ji/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
```

Как решить проблему установки?

Answer (score 0):

Debian/Ubuntu

В системах Debian и Ubuntu существуют различные проблемы, которые могут быть вызваны тем, как упакованы и настроены различные компоненты стандартной библиотеки Python.

> Примечание: Это также может повлиять на пользователей WSL в Windows.

Схема установки:

Обойти эту проблему можно установив для переменной окружения `DEB_PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT` значение `deb`, чтобы эмулировать ранее работавшее поведение.

```
export DEB_PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT=deb
```

Далее просто производим установку `Poetry`:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

Вывод терминала:

```
Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

/home/em0ji/.local/bin

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.2.2): Done

Poetry (1.2.2) is installed now. Great!

You can test that everything is set up by executing:

`poetry --version`
```

Проблема решена.